# Change the image of button when someone made change in different device

Tags: ios, swift, multiplayer

I'm making multiplayer tic tac toe now using Swift. Currently, two users can read the same document in Firestore. I run the app on iPhone 11 simulator which is the right device in the image. After two players tap buttons (the tappable button is the empty plate in the image, and after the player taps the button, the image becomes either apple or pineapple), it is supposed to change image of another device button.

[image]

Here is my code for changing the image of the button which I wrote in viewdidload, but as you can see in the image, I'm still not able to reflect changes if another player makes a change.

```
func changeImage() {
    db.collection(K.FStore.newGameCollection).document(gameDocumentID)
        .addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
            if let err = error {
                print("Error getting documents1: \(err)")
            } else {
                if let data = documentSnapshot!.data() {
                    let gameBordArr = data[K.FStore.gameBoardField] as! [String]
                    for (index, fruit) in gameBordArr.enumerated() {
                        print("tagnumber: \(index), fruit: \(fruit), board: \(gameBordArr)")
                        if let button =  self.view.viewWithTag(index) as? UIButton {
                            print("button \(button)")
                            if fruit == "" {
                                button.setImage(UIImage(named: K.Image.plate), for: .normal)
                            } else {
                                button.setImage(UIImage(named: fruit), for: .highlighted)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

As I mentioned, I ran the app on the right device, and one of the prints inside of the for loop of changeImage function is something like this

> tagnumber: 8, fruit: pineapple, board: ["", "", "", "apple", "apple", "pineapple", "pineapple", "apple", "pineapple"]
>
> button <UIButton: 0x7f98bcca8400; frame = (254 0; 119 119); opaque =
> NO; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 8; layer = <CALayer: 0x600001de3d00>>

The right device (iPhone11) is now accessing the array of the gameboard (`["", "", "", "apple", "apple", "pineapple", "pineapple", "apple", "pineapple"]`), and it can see the pineapple string which another player made a change at tag number 8, which is the right bottom square of the tic tac toe.
[image]

So using that tag number, I think I can access each button on the device and automatically changes the image of the button...

I thought I wrote the correct code in order to reflect the change made by another player, but still, it doesn't work...
I think I make a mistake, but not really sure which part I should fix. Could anyone point that out for me please?

Comment: You are setting the image for `.highlighted` state of the button. try changing it to `.normal`

Comment: Also, UI related changes must happen on the main thread therefor dispatch to main queue when assigning images

Comment: @Jithin and Alex Thank you so much you all! I was able to display both apples and pineapples depending on the change of player2. I really appreciate it!!